# Chrome cannot auto wrap lines in view-source:// after update to v87.0.4280.67

Tags: html, google-chrome, scrollbar, view-source

Before I updating chrome, when I go to `view-source://` of Chrome, It'll auto wrap line(so there'is no horizontal scrollbar).But after I updating Chrome to v87.0.4280.67，It shows horizontal scrollbar and most sites(see vue/react build html in one line) show one line in source code.

How can I make Chrome show html in `view-source://` auto wrap lines, without horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Fixed in Chrome v88

Comment: Broken again in Chrome, 2021/03/24.

Comment: C'MON GOOGLE! WTF?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you 4 solutions:

1-Use view-current-source extension on chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-current-source/bloebkffnmchginelkmdcemamcdeamei?hl=en

2-downgrade to older chrome version :
https://community.progress.com/s/article/How-to-downgrade-to-an-Older-version-of-Chrome

3-wait for next version.

4-try to find related option(if exist) in chrome://settings or chrome://flags At your own risk.I could not find it.